# Finding two nodes with the maximum common connections

Tags: python, graph

I have a CSV where each line is a connection between two nodes, i.e. the line "100,200" means that nodes with IDs 100 and 200 are connected. I am trying to find the two nodes in the file with the maximum number of common connections. For example, if A and B are connected, B and C are connected, but A and C are not connected, then B is a common connection of A and C.

My approach so far has been to create a dictionary of connections, where the key is the ID of the node and the value is a set with all the connections' IDs. Then, I iterate through this, and calculate the intersection of the connections of every pair of members trying to find the maximum intersection size. This works, but takes around 1 hour in Python for a dataset of 10M connections/200k nodes parallelized across 40 cores.

Is there a better approach to this that can avoid the obvious combinatorial explosion?

Comment: Have you explored the networkx module?  I think that might ease this a lot.

Comment: I tried it initially in networkx actually but I'm not familiar enough with graph algorithm nomenclature to know exactly which algorithm/function I'm looking for once I have the graph constructed. Any ideas?

Comment: How large is your data set? You could just load the data into Neo4j with `LOAD CSV` (or with one of the Python drivers) and run a Cypher query. If the data set is small and this is a one-off operation then maybe it's not worth it.

Comment: Unfortunately I've only used networkx for simple things here and there, like calculating transitive closures and such, otherwise I would have put it into an answer for you.  But I'm pretty sure it will have a solution to this.  Sorry!

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from running a DBMS like [neo4j](https://neo4j.com/) or [blazegraph](https://www.blazegraph.com/)? Or using python library like [rdflib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rdflib/)?

Comment: So now I'm trying it with neo4j. I was able to load in the connection graph pretty easily but the query itself is still taking > 1 hr. This is the Cyper query: 
`MATCH (a:Member)-[r:CONNECTED_TO]->(:Member)<-[:CONNECTED_TO]-(b:Member)
    WHERE NOT a=b
WITH a, b, count(r) AS commonConnectionCount
RETURN a.member_id, b.member_id, commonConnectionCount ORDER BY commonConnectionCount DESC LIMIT 10`
which would give me the top 10 member pairs with the most common connections.